# Using rsync to Sync two external HDDs, keep getting permission error

Tags: permissions, osx, rsync

I am trying to set up a rsync script using automator for one of users in the office, but I keep getting an error. I started from the simplest code line:

```
 rsync -a /Volumes/DiskA/ /Volumes/DiskB
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/DiskA/.Trashes" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

I have searched the whole internet and have tried many different ways/codes but still getting error. I also tried a clean installation and formatted the HDDs. I am planning to add other commands one I get this issue fixed. I greatly appreciate if you could help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two issues here

1. Your script doesn't have enough permissions (privileges) to access the files in diskA's Trash. This appears to be OSX so I can't advise you how to get root permissions; `sudo` or `su` is what I'd use on other UNIX-like platforms.
2. You probably don't want to copy Trash anyway. Add in the `--exclude '/.Trashes'` option to your `rsync` for this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, unfortunately I got a situation at work yesterday and had to take care of it. Thanks for the tips, I will definitely try it and will update my post.

Comment: The exclude option worked. That's wierd cuz I had tried it before and it failed. Magic! Thanks again.

Comment: roaima, if the poster says your answer has fixed his problem, ask him to accept the question. Otherwise the poster will disappear, never to be heard of again, and the question will be stuck in limbo.

Comment: @FaheemMitha usually I do. Let's see if the OP sees these comments (they were last on SE just a week ago, so it's possible).

Comment: I think one needs to explicitly reference his username. I.e. @AvaHr to draw his attention.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was ACL rules on some files. Run `getfacl /folder/file` to see extended rules if any are set.

In my case, some files had extended permission rules, so `rsync` couldn't read them.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I included the details you added in your comment into the question body. All relevant information is expected to be in the answer itself here. You might want to take the [tour] or look through our [help] to understand how the site works better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, I think you should choose more carefully the options of rsync. The option `-a` equals to `-rlptgoD`, so `rsync` tries to preserve permissions, owner and group of your files from a disk to another. For example for my backups I use the options:

```
rsync -urtDvx --delete /volume/diskA/ /volume/diskB/
```

and it works fine for me. These options mean:

```
 -u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
 -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
 -t, --times                 preserve modification times
 -D                          preserve special and device files (super-user only)
 -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
 -x, --one-file-system       don't cross filesystem boundaries
 --delete                    delete extraneous files from dest dirs
```

I suggest you to check out the manual of `rsync` to find out what options are best for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, unfortunately I got a situation at work yesterday and had to take care of it. Thanks for the tips, I will definitely try it and will update my post.

Comment: Also can you tell me what exactly urtDvx do?

Comment: @AvaHr that's what the man page is for. Try `man rsync` either at the terminal command line or even in Google

Comment: @AvaHr and/or andreastsh (if you are the same person do check out how to merge accounts): if the answer worked for you please could you accept it with the (green) tick mark on the left side. Thanks.